# How many rows will be locked by SELECT … ORDER BY xxx LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE?

Tags: postgresql, locking, deadlock

As was asked on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5694658/1023341) but then for MySQL, I was wondering how this works in PostgreSQL. How many rows get locked when I do a "FOR UPDATE" in combination with a "LIMIT", a "ORDER BY" and some "WHERE"'s. And they update the returned row. I was hoping the "FOR UPDATE"-query would only lock ONE row but maybe I miss some implementations issue. (I'm planning to write some stress-test to reproduce this more reliably)

These queries cause a deadlock in my system:

```
(session1) select field1, field2, ... from documents where transaction_path='some/path' for update
(session2) select field1, field2, ... from documents where (transaction_path is null) and queue_id=2 and next_pickup_ts<now() order by next_pickup_ts limit 1 for update
(session3) select field1, field2, ... from documents where (transaction_path is null) and queue_id=2 and next_pickup_ts<now() order by next_pickup_ts limit 1 for update
```

But I do not understand why. (There is a unique index on transaction_path.)

Comment: I'm sure when statement gets executed only one row is locked (`LIMIT 1`). However, during execution of the statement the engine may put locks on all records that satisfy `WHERE` (note, order on which rows are actually locked is never guaranteed). I'm not postgres guy, so I can't state this is what happens in your case, but it would explain deadlocks.

Comment: The docs say " If a LIMIT is used, locking stops once enough rows have been returned to satisfy the limit (but note that rows skipped over by OFFSET will get locked).. ". Can you explain exactly what you mean by "deadlock": do you get a "deadlock detected..." error in your postmaster log? If not, how did you determine you have a deadlock condition? (I would expect session 3 to possibly have to wait until session 2 has committed.)

Comment: Don't try to roll your own queue system. You'll either get something that performs the same as a single serial worker, or something that's wrong.

Comment: Please show the query plans for the relevant queries, from `EXPLAIN`. Also show the output of the deadlock detected error message, if that's what you get, and if not please properly explain what you mean by "cause a deadlock".

Comment: Thanks @CraigRinger: point about 'roll your own' taken. But in this case the worker-speed is not high. And the deployment team cannot currently handle a full-blown MQ. Hence the poor-man solution. Will try-out your answer and mark it as accepted when it works (which I don't doubt)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you use [`EXPLAIN`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-explain.html) you'll see the ordering. For a random plan I concocted with some throwaway data and similar query (`ORDER BY ... LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE`) I got the plan:

```
 Limit  (cost=33.09..33.10 rows=1 width=26)
   ->  LockRows  (cost=33.09..39.88 rows=543 width=26)
         ->  Sort  (cost=33.09..34.45 rows=543 width=26)
               Sort Key: t_id
               ->  Seq Scan on m  (cost=0.00..30.38 rows=543 width=26)
                     Filter: (b_id <= 33)
(6 rows)
```

Here, you can see the rows are potentially locked *before* the limit is applied.

Now, in practice, the first row that gets matched will generally get locked and returned, causing `LockRows` on the later rows to get skipped ... but there's no guarantee of this. So you shouldn't rely on it.

In general, mixing row-locking and `LIMIT` is a bad idea that should generally be avoided.

If you must do it, you'll want to do something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM my_table 
            WHERE mywhereclause 
            ORDER BY ... LIMIT 1)
  AND mywhereclause
FOR UPDATE;
```

where you force a target row to be found, and only then locked.

You should repeat the WHERE clause in the outer query to ensure that the row still matches the predicate after any lock-wait occurs. Otherwise what can happen is that the inner query finds the row, returns the ID, and you try to lock the row with that ID. PostgreSQL sees that someone else has a lock on that row, so it waits for that lock to be released. Then it re-checks the `WHERE` clause on the outer query to make sure it still matches (in case the row was deleted, or was `UPDATE`d). Because the inner query is an uncorrelated subquery it *won't* re-calculate it, though, so the inner `WHERE` clause doesn't get re-run, and you can get rows that no longer match the inner `WHERE` clause returned if you don't repeat it in the outer `WHERE` clause.

Mixing row limits and row locking is hard. Building correct queuing systems that actually perform better than a single worker is even harder. Use an off the shelf queuing system and save yourself a lot of hassle.

([PostgreSQL 9.5 will have `SKIP LOCKED`](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What%27s_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.5#SKIP_LOCKED), which makes this way easier, but there won't be a stable release of it for over a year from now, so don't hold your breath.)

Comment: `SKIP LOCKED` exists now but `FOR UPDATE` still doesn't respect `LIMIT`.

Answer (score -2):

Postgres will lock only 1 record that return from **LIMIT** clause.
The reason other concurrent query has to wait because the **SELECT ... WHERE ... LIMIT 1** return the same record, that being locked by the first query in other transaction, so It is blocked and waiting.
Correct solution is using **SKIP LOCKED** clause after *FOR UPDATE* clause in query, no need to have subquery.

Comment: This seems to contradict what Craig says in his answer (with experimental proof!).  Could you please explain the difference?

Comment: You can open 2 transaction and test with these 2 simple query:
```SELECT id FROM test_table LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE```

```SELECT id FROM test_table LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED```

with second query, even the first transaction is not committed, second transaction still has  result, that mean the query lock only 1 row, not all row of table.